# Calculation doesnt work

Tags: java, if-statement

Account balance = 107000. When the user inputs 106500 it will give the else statement. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
while (menuChoice == 1) {                   

            System.out.println("How much do you want to transfer?");
            transferAmount = console.nextDouble(); // Getting transfer amount
                                                // from user input
            System.out.println("Who do you want to transfer this to?");
            transferName = console.next(); // Getting a transfer name from user input
            accountBalance = (accountBalance - transferAmount); // The calculation for account balance

            if (accountBalance > transferAmount) { // Only allowing transfer if the transfer amount is less than the account balance
                System.out.println(""); // spacing out the output
                System.out.println("Transfer Complete");
                outfile.println("The balance for the port account is £"+ accountBalance + "  You have sent £"+ transferAmount + " to " + transferName+ "  on the following date and time,  " + Date); // Printing line to output file about the transaction details
                outfile.close();
                menuChoice = 0; // Ending the while loop if true



            } else  // Denying a transfer if the transfer amount is more than the account balance
                System.out.println("Warning You will go overdrawn!");
            menuChoice = 0;

        }
```

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: What do you think the following statement does: `accountBalance = (accountBalance - transferAmount);`?

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting the transfer amount from the balance before deciding if it is safe to do so:

```
accountBalance = (accountBalance - transferAmount);
```

This should only happen after you have decided there are enough funds to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

if accountbalance > transferamount then you have to subtract accountBalance = (accountBalance - transferAmount); 
do this inside if statement .